# Easiest way to right align numbers in span. Can't figure it out

Tags: html, css

This should be easy but can't seem to figure out what's going on. I need to have the numbers in the below screen shot align right - they're aligning left. I tried text-aligning right but that doesn't seem to do much. Any ideas? thanks
     [image]

Here's the markup.

```
<a class="tile" data-bind="attr: { href: $root.getSearchPath($data) }" href="/#products/quicksearch/_test-my_products">
    <div class="left">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text:$data.display_name, attr: { title: $data.display_name }" title="Example Product Search">Example Product Search</span>
    </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
          <span class="number">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin loader" data-bind="visible:($data.loading())" style="display: none;"></i>
                <span data-bind="visible:(!$data.loading()), text: $data.count" style="">51</span>
            </span>
</a>

//SCSS

  .tile {
    color: $tundora;
    display:flex;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid $alto;
    //width:190px;
    margin:0 14px 20px 0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color: $gallery;
    line-height:15px;
    height:67px;
    transition: background .1s ease-out;
  }

  .number {
   display:inline-flex;  
   margin:0 0 0 18px;
   font-size:$font-largest;
   align-items:center;
   width:73px;
   text-align:right
  }

  .left {
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: tried that :) - didn't work

Comment: the .number element

Comment: okay, i turned your code into a snippet, maybe you don 't share enough to show the issue.

Comment: At first sight setting `justify-content: flex-end` on `.number` should do work. On mobile I cannot test it, though.

Comment: Try `justify-content: flex-end` on `.number`.

Comment: inline-flex comes in the way, what do you need it for ?

Comment: @G-Cyr the snippet is not good ... I think better keep the initial code, there is a lot of variable that doesn't belong to html/css

Comment: @TemaniAfif initial code and snippet code are similar. feel free to roll it back ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr yes exactly, and since it doesn't reproduce the image or the issue better keep it simple code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `justify-content: flex-end;` to `.number` selector.

```css
.tile {
  color: $tundora;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid $alto;
  //width:190px;
  margin: 0 14px 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: $gallery;
  line-height: 15px;
  height: 67px;
  transition: background .1s ease-out;
}

.number {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 18px;
  font-size: $font-largest;
  align-items: center;
  width: 73px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="tile" data-bind="attr: { href: $root.getSearchPath($data) }" href="/#products/quicksearch/_test-my_products">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="title" data-bind="text:$data.display_name, attr: { title: $data.display_name }" title="Example Product Search">Example Product Search</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <span class="number">
     <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin loader" data-bind="visible:($data.loading())" style="display: none;"></i>
     <span data-bind="visible:(!$data.loading()), text: $data.count" style="">51</span>
  </span>
</a>
```